# Apache2 listening on port 443 even though sites-available config files don't list it

Tags: apache-2.2, https

I removed the symbolic links from /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.  I created a config file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ which specifies my HTTP only site for port 80.  Then I create the symbolic link from sites-available/my.conf to sites-enabled and ran service apache2 restart.  My site came up and all is well.  Several days later I ran ss -a and find that apache2 is listening on 443.  The is no site-enabled config to tell it to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Apache load everything under site-enabled AND apache.conf. Check in that file if you don't have instructions that would make it listen to 443 or includes other files that would.

Answer (score 1):

Apache httpd listens on IP's and ports configured with the [`Listen`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#Listen) directive. These are setup before any of your sites are configured. Generally `80` will be in httpd.conf or apache.conf. `443` may be in a seperate ssl config file.

To find them al:

```
grep -r Listen /etc/apache2/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache includes a file in /etc/apache2 called ports.conf

Remove it from there and restart apache. This will break any SSL sites you have configured